# combination of elements of sets

Tags: python, dictionary, set, combinations

I have a dictionary.

```
d = {
    'Cause Class': {'CC1', 'CC2'},
    'Cause Type': {'Ct1', 'Ct2', 'Ct3', 'Ct4'},
    'Incident Type': {'It1', 'It2', 'It3'}
}
```

I want to find the combinations of two elements of which each element must be from different keys of dict.

for example: `('CC1', 'Ct1')` is one such combination whereas `('Ct1', 'Ct2')` is not.

I have tried this

```
ksgg = []
for i in d:
    #print(i)
    for j in d:
        if i != j:
            ksgg.append(list(set(it.product(d[i],d[j]))))
```

but it's giving `('CC1', 'Ct1')` and `('Ct1', 'CC1')` as two different combination but I want only one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a nested loop over the keys, pass all values to [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations); it'll pick unique combinations of a given length:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

ksgg = []
for set1, set2 in combinations(d.values(), 2):
    ksgg += product(set1, set2)
```

For your given dictionary, the following combinations are created:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations, product
>>> for set1, set2 in combinations(d, 2):
...     print(set1, set2, sep=' - ')
...
Cause Class - Cause Type
Cause Class - Incident Type
Cause Type - Incident Type
```

The exact order of the pairing differs based on dictionary ordering.

Full demo:

```
>>> ksgg = []
>>> for set1, set2 in combinations(d.values(), 2):
...     ksgg += product(set1, set2)
...
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(ksgg)
[('CC1', 'Ct4'),
 ('CC1', 'Ct2'),
 ('CC1', 'Ct1'),
 ('CC1', 'Ct3'),
 ('CC2', 'Ct4'),
 ('CC2', 'Ct2'),
 ('CC2', 'Ct1'),
 ('CC2', 'Ct3'),
 ('CC1', 'It2'),
 ('CC1', 'It1'),
 ('CC1', 'It3'),
 ('CC2', 'It2'),
 ('CC2', 'It1'),
 ('CC2', 'It3'),
 ('Ct4', 'It2'),
 ('Ct4', 'It1'),
 ('Ct4', 'It3'),
 ('Ct2', 'It2'),
 ('Ct2', 'It1'),
 ('Ct2', 'It3'),
 ('Ct1', 'It2'),
 ('Ct1', 'It1'),
 ('Ct1', 'It3'),
 ('Ct3', 'It2'),
 ('Ct3', 'It1'),
 ('Ct3', 'It3')]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted.